# Integrating HTML 5 video players(jplayer) in sencha touch app

Tags: sencha-touch-2, html5-video, jplayer

Is it good practice to use html5 video players like [jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) in my sencha touch app?

If so, where can we instantiate the player?
Also, where do we write the html code for player? This [demo](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-video/) has both the javascript and html part.

Comment: One way I found out is writing html code in painted event in view, after the javascript is loaded.

Comment: References to third party scripts can be made in your app.json file... check out sencha command in the st2 docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References to the third party scripts can be made in app.json file if we used sencha command to deploy. However mine was not that case so adding them in index.html worked fine.

Instantiation of the player can be done anywhere. But to make sure the instantiation was done after the DOM part of the html code was executed, go to the view in which html was written and write the javascript part in a painted function.